# How to update a field in MongoDB using Java driver with the value of another field in the collection?

Tags: java, mongodb

I am using MongoDB with Java driver. I am trying to update a field by multiplying another with a number and setting it. But instead of the result of the multiplication, the field is being set by a `BasicDBObject`. How do I make it so that the result is set?

Please give the answer using the [Update builders](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/java/sync/current/fundamentals/builders/updates/) of the Java driver?

```
Bson filter1 = and(
        eq("platform", platform),
        eq("channel", channel)
);
double percent = 20;
final Bson update = set("percent_view", new BasicDBObject("$multiply", Arrays.asList("$viewtime", percent)));

collection.updateOne(filter1, update);
```